# Is it possible AVRCP on BLE with iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, avrcp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on the `iOS` app to control music player over `Bluetooth LE`. I have BLE enabled peripheral device (Wearable Watch) and it will act as a music remote controller. I came to know that `AVRCP` profile is the option provided by iOS to control music on iPhone, but this profile is based on classic Bluetooth profile(Not on BLE).

**Edited:**

**Is there any way for controlling Music player using iOS BLE service?**

Can Please provide me the suggestion to control music player (Play, Pause, Next and Previous) on iPhone using BLE service?

I was refer this links

[What specs do I need to know to develop bluetooth (AVRCP 1.4) iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177887/what-specs-do-i-need-to-know-to-develop-bluetooth-avrcp-1-4-iphone-app)

[iOS Bluetooth dual-mode; connect BLE (GATT) to an already connected BR/EDR (A2DP/HFP) stereo headset simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056668/ios-bluetooth-dual-mode-connect-ble-gatt-to-an-already-connected-br-edr-a2dp)

[What profile can I use with CoreBluetooth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768599/what-profile-can-i-use-with-corebluetooth)

Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

AVRCP is a BR/EDR profile. It is not available on LE. LE only accepts the items listed in the *GATT-Based Specifications* part of [adopted specifications page](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/adopted-specifications).

You could implement a HID profile (used for input devices) on your device, then you may send key presses for Play/Pause, Next, Previous, Volume up/down, Mute, etc.. Most multimedia keys work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question was only about iOS the correct answer is to use Apple's proprietary GATT protocol, which has been developed already in 2014.

> The Apple Media Service (AMS) is used with Bluetooth accessories that connect to iOS devices through Bluetooth low-energy links. It gives them a simple and convenient way to control media apps and access information about the media states of the connected iOS devices.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleMediaService_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html